# hide output of aplay shell command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

Is there a way to hide the **output** of the [**aplay**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/aplay.1.html) command when play a sound?

I tried this without success

```
$ aplay ~/.zsh/sounds/done.wav >> /dev/null

Playing WAVE '/home/oscar/.zsh/sounds/done.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 11025 Hz, Mono
```

I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried the `-q` option mentioned on the man page you linked?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply add the `-q` option:

```
aplay -q ~/.zsh/sounds/done.wav
```

No need to redirect stdout to /dev/null there.

Another note: `aplay` actuall sends messages to /dev/stderr (fd 2). You can also nullify the output by sending it to /dev/null:

```
aplay ~/.zsh/sounds/done.wav 2>/dev/null
```

You can see more options with `aplay --help`. This line is about `-q`:

```
-q, --quiet             quiet mode
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice that. It works like a charm :)